# Find the input box that is made hidden using hide() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find the input box that is made hidden using `hide()` in jQquery?

```js
$("#tab1").on('click', 'td button.save', function() {
  var $thisParent = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").hide().end().html('<span>' + $thisParent + '</span>');
});

// Here, this portion is not working:
$("#tab1").on('click', 'td span.edit', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").show();
  alert($(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").prop("tagName"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tab1" width="80%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input class="fillcolumn" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<span class="edit">&#x270E;</span>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<span class="remove">&#x2718;</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      Weightage: &#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;
      <select>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="save">Save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above code is not working, I mean, it is not turn the `input box` `on` with its value. Any help?

Comment: Please make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: Why are you finding an `input` and then trying to retrieve its `tagName`? Its `tagName` is what you used to find it in the first place - except it's in upper-case, I suppose. But this feels somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things need to be changed,

- The appended `span` does not have `edit` class, so the click won't fire.
- Use `append()` instead of `html()` as `html()` deletes the `<input>` tag.
- Instead of `.parent().parent()` use `.closest()`

---

```
$(this).closest('tr')
       .find("td:eq(1)")
       .find("input").hide().end()
       .append('<span class="edit">' + $thisParent + '</span>');
```

### Demo

```js
$("#tab1").on('click', 'td button.save', function() {
  var $thisParent = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").find("input").hide().end().append('<span class="edit">' + $thisParent + '</span>');
});

// Here, this portion is not working 
$("#tab1").on('click', 'td span.edit', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").find("input").show();
  alert($(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").prop("tagName"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tab1" width="80%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input class="fillcolumn" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<span class="edit">&#x270E;</span>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<span class="remove">&#x2718;</span>
    </td>
    <td>Weightage: &#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;
      <select>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="save">Save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Further improved use of selectors. Refer **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmqsc4h9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

instead of `html()` use `append()`

```
$("#tab1").on('click', 'td button.save', function(){ 
    var $thisParent = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val(); 
    $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").find("input").hide().end().append('<span>' + $thisParent + '</span>');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call save the input is removed from the page. 
I guess what you want to do is hide the input when save is clicked and add in a new span with the value from the input?

this should help you move on:
http://jsbin.com/pufiroxolo/1/edit?html,js,output

but like @Shaunack D says lots of optimisations can be done with this! I've just used what was provided so not to confuse things!

Answer (score 0):

When you call JQuery hide() on a DOM element, JQuery adds the style attribute for the dom as ***display:none***.

You can do a *find()* using jquery for all text boxes and then check if each textbox has the style display: none.
Something like this

```
var listOfHidden = []
$($.find("input")).each(function()
{
  if ($(this).css("display") == 'none'){listOfHidden.push(this)}
});
//variable listOfHidden will have the list of all hidden text
```